# Why is compressibility $\kappa=(1/\rho^2) \partial\rho/\partial\mu$?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am currently studying Giamarchi's book "Quantum Physics in One Dimension". This book defines the compressibility as usual,
$$\kappa=-\frac{1}{V} \frac{\partial V}{\partial P}$$
and with no explanation this book says that
$$\kappa=\frac{1}{\rho^2} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \mu},$$
where $\rho=N/V$ is the density. I am even not sure whether $\kappa$ is $\kappa_S$ or $\kappa_T$, i.e. which variable is held fixed. How can I understand this equation?

Comment: What is mu defined as?

Comment: Perhaps the first equation is the compressibility of a solid, where the difference between isothermal and isentropic compressibility is usually negligible?

Comment: @ChetMiller As usual, $\mu$ is the chemical potential.

Comment: Then the units don’t seem to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

For solids $N$ is a constant. 
$$G=\mu N=U-TS+PV$$
$$Nd\mu=TdS-PdV-TdS-SdT+PdV+VdP=-SdT+VdP$$
Which gives,
$$ {(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial P})}_{T,N}=\frac{V}{N}=\frac{1}{\rho}$$
Now  apply chain rule, you will get the answer. $$\kappa _T=-\frac{1}{V} \frac{\partial V}{\partial P}=-\frac{1}{V} \frac{\partial V}{\partial \mu}\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial P}$$ 
As you can see, here we keep $T$ and $N $ as constants.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and lucid answer!